# Query returning too few results after adding NOT LIKE condition

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an Access 2010 Database that is behaving oddly when I slightly altered a query that a user requested.  I have one very large table (don't ask) that the query runs on and then feeds to a user input form.  Anyway, today, one particular form started returning a lot less results than we expected.  It normally returns about 1200 results, but after the minor change, that dropped to 880 results.  When I was checking it, it should only have dropped to 1100, so I am missing an additional 300 expected results.

I build my queries to this table in layers to keep things from getting too strange.  I'm not great with sql, so I usually build just using the design view.  I can muddle through in sql if I have to.

Here is the SQL to the first layer

```
SELECT [New ZSPWAR Prime].Payer, [New ZSPWAR Prime].Bill_doc, [New ZSPWAR Prime].Sqwak, [New ZSPWAR Prime].Billing_Dt, [New ZSPWAR Prime].Issued_Material, [New ZSPWAR Prime].Serial_No, [New ZSPWAR Prime].[review date], [New ZSPWAR Prime].Mtrl_Qty_Billed, [New ZSPWAR Prime].PO_DT, [New ZSPWAR Prime].PO_NO, [New ZSPWAR Prime].PO_PI, [New ZSPWAR Prime].INV_PT_DT, [New ZSPWAR Prime].[Warr Typ], [New ZSPWAR Prime].Stage, [New ZSPWAR Prime].Returned_Material, [New ZSPWAR Prime].Returned_SNR, [New ZSPWAR Prime].Ret_EQUI, [New ZSPWAR Prime].Sales_Ord, [New ZSPWAR Prime].SVO_No, [New ZSPWAR Prime].[ME23N PO_Owner], [New ZSPWAR Prime].Ret_Note, [New ZSPWAR Prime].Ret_Date, [New ZSPWAR Prime].Ret_Note_DESC, [New ZSPWAR Prime].WACD, [New ZSPWAR Prime].Wty_Prog_Code_Desc, [New ZSPWAR Prime].VR_Amount, [New ZSPWAR Prime].Freight_Amt, [New ZSPWAR Prime].VDCD, [New ZSPWAR Prime].Ven_Den_Code_Desc, [New ZSPWAR Prime].ZZ07, [New ZSPWAR Prime].[root cause] AS [Email Follow Up], [New ZSPWAR Prime].[Step 1 Complete], [New ZSPWAR Prime].[Step 1 notes], [New ZSPWAR Prime].[Step 2 complete], [New ZSPWAR Prime].[step 2 notes], [New ZSPWAR Prime].[Step 3 complete], [New ZSPWAR Prime].[step 3 notes], [New ZSPWAR Prime].[Push INV_PMT], [New ZSPWAR Prime].[PO Due Date]
FROM [New ZSPWAR Prime]
WHERE ((([New ZSPWAR Prime].Payer) Not Like "10208" And ([New ZSPWAR Prime].Payer) Not Like "2300" And ([New ZSPWAR Prime].Payer) Not Like "32770") AND (([New ZSPWAR Prime].Billing_Dt)>#7/1/2016#) AND (([New ZSPWAR Prime].Mtrl_Qty_Billed)>0) AND (([New ZSPWAR Prime].PO_NO) Not Like "" And ([New ZSPWAR Prime].PO_NO) Is Not Null) AND (([New ZSPWAR Prime].[Step 3 complete])<>Yes));
```

And here is the second:

```
SELECT [Day2Day InvPmt a].Payer, [Day2Day InvPmt a].Bill_doc, [Day2Day InvPmt a].Sqwak, [Day2Day InvPmt a].Billing_Dt, [Day2Day InvPmt a].Issued_Material, [Day2Day InvPmt a].Serial_No, [Day2Day InvPmt a].[review date], [Day2Day InvPmt a].Mtrl_Qty_Billed, [Day2Day InvPmt a].PO_DT, [Day2Day InvPmt a].PO_NO, [Day2Day InvPmt a].PO_PI, [Day2Day InvPmt a].INV_PT_DT, [Day2Day InvPmt a].[Warr Typ], [Day2Day InvPmt a].Stage, [Day2Day InvPmt a].Returned_Material, [Day2Day InvPmt a].Returned_SNR, [Day2Day InvPmt a].Ret_EQUI, [Day2Day InvPmt a].Sales_Ord, [Day2Day InvPmt a].SVO_No, [Day2Day InvPmt a].[ME23N PO_Owner], [Day2Day InvPmt a].Ret_Note, [Day2Day InvPmt a].Ret_Date, [Day2Day InvPmt a].Ret_Note_DESC, [Day2Day InvPmt a].WACD, [Day2Day InvPmt a].Wty_Prog_Code_Desc, [Day2Day InvPmt a].VR_Amount, [Day2Day InvPmt a].Freight_Amt, [Day2Day InvPmt a].VDCD, [Day2Day InvPmt a].Ven_Den_Code_Desc, [Day2Day InvPmt a].ZZ07, [Day2Day InvPmt a].[Email Follow Up], [Day2Day InvPmt a].[Step 1 Complete], [Day2Day InvPmt a].[Step 1 notes], [Day2Day InvPmt a].[Step 2 complete], [Day2Day InvPmt a].[step 2 notes], [Day2Day InvPmt a].[Step 3 complete], [Day2Day InvPmt a].[step 3 notes], [Day2Day InvPmt a].[Push INV_PMT], [Day2Day InvPmt a].[PO Due Date]
FROM [Day2Day InvPmt a]
WHERE ((([Day2Day InvPmt a].INV_PT_DT) Is Null) AND (([Day2Day InvPmt a].[Step 1 notes]) Not Like "*" & "windsh*")) OR ((([Day2Day InvPmt a].INV_PT_DT) Like "") AND (([Day2Day InvPmt a].[Step 1 notes]) Not Like "*" & "windsh*"))
ORDER BY [Day2Day InvPmt a].Bill_doc;
```

The culprit is this little bit here:

```
WHERE ((([Day2Day InvPmt a].INV_PT_DT) Is Null) AND (([Day2Day InvPmt a].[Step 1 notes]) Not Like "*" & "windsh*")) OR ((([Day2Day InvPmt a].INV_PT_DT) Like "") AND (([Day2Day InvPmt a].[Step 1 notes]) Not Like "*" & "windsh*"))
```

The part excluding "windsh*" is the recent addition and source of confusion.

Prior to adding that little bit, I was getting 1200 returns.  After, I get 880.  I tried to build this in reverse and There are only 100 or that should have been filtered out, and I have no idea why it's doing this.  Any ideas, or has this been answered elsewhere in here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could probably simplify the where clause for 
[Day2Day InvPmt a].INV_PT_DT by using
`WHERE Len([Day2Day InvPmt a].INV_PT_DT & "") >0  AND [Day2Day InvPmt a].[Step 1 notes]) Not Like "*windsh*"` 
Which should speed up the query as well. Are you sure you want the wildcard before and after windsh ?

Comment: @Minty I need the wildcard before and after because I am dealing with an inconsistent naming convention.  I confess I'm not quite sure why the "LEN" thing would be useful

Comment: Does `SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM [Day2Day InvPmt a] WHERE Nz(INV_PT_DT, "") = "" AND [Step 1 notes] LIKE "*windsh*"` return a reasonable value for the number of additional rows that you would like to have excluded?

Comment: @GordThompson ,no it isn't.  It returns about 100 values  If thisg were consistent, It should return around 400

Comment: Your question seems to suggest that ~100 rows actually *is* what you expected to see excluded when you added the condition.

Comment: @GordThompson, I may not have been clear.  the original result without the addition was about 1200 record.  of those, about 100 meet the condition, so when I exclude them with "not like windsh" I should have 1100.  The actual result is about 800.  That is 300 dropping out for no known reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Not Like` operator does not match Null values even though a Null value apparently does not match the pattern.  You need to explicitly (re)include Nulls.

Within Design View on the criteria grid you enter something like

```
Not Like "*windsh*" Or Is Null
```

Within the SQL statement is should look something like

```
(([Day2Day InvPmt a].[Step 1 notes]) Not Like "*windsh*" Or ([Day2Day InvPmt a].[Step 1 notes]) Is Null)
```

Comment: Bingo!  That did the trick.  Thank you so much.  It matches what I got when manually manipulating everything in excel as well

Comment: Great!  NULL is the first red flag that pops up in my mind when I get frustrating query results.  There are sets of rules for how Null values propagate through Boolean operations, but its not always immediately intuitive so I wouldn't assume anything without specific testing.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind next time it comes up.  I had no ide it could screw things up this bad

Comment: I'm pretty certain the Len() bit would have captured this, as it checks for both Null and zero length strings, which are not the same thing. Glad you sorted it.

Comment: @Minty  Your code was attempting to simplify the condition on `[Day2Day InvPmt a].INV_PT_DT` and that might be useful. Technically you got the expression wrong since it should have had an equal sign like `Len([Day2Day InvPmt a].INV_PT_DT & "") = 0` to match the original condition.  But your comment didn't address where the problem was occurring with the Not Like operation and the `[Step 1 notes]` field, so it's not clear what you mean.  To be fair, something like `([Day2Day InvPmt a].[Step 1 notes] & "") Not Like "*windsh*"` would also have been sufficient.

Comment: Ah yes should have been = you are correct. I was checking for not null, not enough coffee...