# Not like "*TEST*", <> "TEST", Not Like "*TEST*", Not Like "*TEST", Not Like "TEST*", Not Exists ()

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've tried each of the below without success in an Access Query using Design & SQL.  Nothing Seems to filter OUT anything with a [Status] = "TEST" or "*TEST*" as 'Test' may be anywhere within the [Status] field.

```
Not like "*TEST*" 
<> "TEST"
Not Like "*TEST*"
Not Like "*TEST" 
Not Like "TEST*"
Not Exists (SELECT MainData.* WHERE MainData.Status = "TEST")
```

Full length,

```
SELECT [MainData].*
FROM [Main Data]
WHERE ((([MainData].AMOUNT)<[MainData]![OtherAmount]) 
AND (([MainData].Status) Not Like "TEST"));
```

All works fine until I plug in Not like "TEST"

Thank you in advance!

Comment: See [Why does a LIKE query in Access not return any records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166907/why-does-a-like-query-in-access-not-return-any-records)

Comment: Your question doesn't contain sample data. Please add sample data, expected output, and current output. Now, answers are just guesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of null values, your query cannot find anything. You can use  `NZ` function for eliminating this.

```
SELECT [MainData].*
FROM [MainData]
WHERE (( ([MainData].AMOUNT)<[MainData]![OtherAmount]) 
    AND (( NZ([MainData].Status,"") ) NOT Like "*TEST*"));
```

Comment: Great!  For reference, this is also addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571744/query-returning-too-few-results-after-adding-not-like-condition/45574899#45574899).

Comment: The referenced link helps I was able to use in Design view Not like "TEST" Or Is Null to get it to work.  Thank you for the help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Access SQL the correct syntax is

```
'Excludes everything with "Test" in it (12test34)
SELECT * FROM [Main Data] WHERE [Main Data].Status Not Like "*Test*"

'Excludes everything that starts with "Test" (test34)
SELECT * FROM [Main Data] WHERE [Main Data].Status Not Like "Test*"

'Excludes everything that ends with "Test" (12test)
SELECT * FROM [Main Data] WHERE [Main Data].Status Not Like "*Test"
```

Comment: According to the OP, the first example (which is the catchall solution) does not work.

Comment: Well, there can still be other reasons why it is not working. And you already posted the link with the detailed explanation.

Comment: You're free to answer, I'm just pointing out particulars of the original question.  I posted as a comment and not an answer before knowing the real details of the specific problem. This is essentially a duplicate question.  For years there is ongoing discussion (in meta) about encouraging new users to ask good questions, but too many are slow to actually implement anything.  I do my best to "coach" and encourage great questions by having the OP post complete examples before giving knee-jerk answers that (while perhaps correct and useful) are maybe incomplete and sometimes guesswork.